# Open Office (Calc) Spreadsheet to XML

Tags: python, xml, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I am looking for an automated method to convert a spreadsheet file (open office) into an XML format that corresponds to a LabVIEW cluster and will be imported as an XML file.

I have been recommended to use Python to convert spreadsheet to XML, however I have very limited experience using Python. I tried to find examples online, but most are tailored toward XML to spreadsheet rather than the other way round.

Does anyone hav any advice on how to get values from a spreadsheet automatically into a set XML format?

Any help would be much appreciated!

The required XML format is as follows:

```
<LVData><Version>16.0</Version>
<Cluster><Name>CVT File Data</Name>
<NumElts>2</NumElts>
<Array>
<Name>Tags</Name>
<Dimsize>3</Dimsize>
<Cluster>
<Name>Tag</Name>
<NumElts>4</NumElts>
<EW><Name>Data Type</Name>
<Choice>Double</Choice>
<Choice>Single</Choice>
<Choice>I64</Choice>
<Choice>I32</Choice>
<Choice>I16</Choice>
<Choice>I8</Choice>
<Choice>U64</Choice>
<Choice>U32</Choice>
<Choice>U16</Choice>
<Choice>U8</Choice>
<Choice>String</Choice>
<Choice>Boolean</Choice>
<Choice>Array of U8</Choice>    
<Choice>Array of U16</Choice>
<Choice>Array of U32</Choice>
<Choice>Array of U64</Choice>
<Choice>Array of I64</Choice>
<Choice>Array of I32</Choice>
<Choice>Array of I16</Choice>
<Choice>Array of I8</Choice>
<Choice>Array of Double</Choice>
<Choice>Array of Single</Choice>
<Choice>Array of Boolean</Choice>
<Choice>Array of String</Choice>
<Val>11</Val></EW>
<String>
<Name>Name</Name>
<Val>91Q0-st-CL</Val>
</String>
<String>
<Name>Value</Name>
<Val>T</Val>
</String>
<String>
<Name>Description</Name>
<Val>Status Close</Val>
</String>
</Cluster>
<Cluster>
<Name>Tag</Name>
<NumElts>4</NumElts>
<EW><Name>Data Type</Name>
<Choice>Double</Choice>
</EW>
<String>
<Name>Name</Name>
<Val>91F2-PAE-I</Val>
</String>
<String>
<Name>Value</Name>
<Val>T</Val>
</String>
<String>
<Name>Description</Name>
<Val>Pulse active energy import</Val>
</String>
</Cluster>
<Cluster>
<Name>Tag</Name>
<NumElts>4</NumElts>
<EW><Name>Data Type</Name>
<Choice>Double</Choice>
</EW>
<String>
<Name>Name</Name>
<Val>91F2-PAE-E</Val>
</String>
<String>
<Name>Value</Name>
<Val>T</Val>
</String>
<String>
<Name>Description</Name>
<Val>Pulse active energy export</Val>
</String>
</Cluster>
</Array>
<Array>
<Name>Group Listings</Name>
<Dimsize>1</Dimsize>
<Cluster>
<Name>Tag Grouping</Name>
<NumElts>2</NumElts>
<String>
<Name>Group</Name>
<Val>Active energy</Val>
</String>
<Array>
<Name>Tag Names</Name>
<Dimsize>2</Dimsize>
<String>
<Name>Names</Name>
<Val>91F2-PAE-I</Val>
</String>
<String><Name>Names</Name>
<Val>91F2-PAE-E</Val>
</String>
</Array>
</Cluster>
</Array>
</Cluster>
</LVData>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as reading data out of LibreOffice Calc documents, I have had good luck with Ezodf (https://pythonhosted.org/ezodf/)

One quirk that occasionally results in confusing doc: what was once called a Sheet is now called a Table (clasnames). Both refer to a worksheet.

Some code snippets: Opening a spreadsheet (FILE="path/somefile.ods") and iterating over a subset of its worksheets specified by SHEETS:

```
doc=ezodf.opendoc(FILE)
sheets = doc.sheets
sheetnames = list( sheets.names() )
for name in SHEETS: 
    print( "Starting sheet '{}'".format( name ))
    do_sheet( sheets[name] )

def do_sheet( sheet ):
    ...
```

Accessing a cell in a worksheet can be by `"A1" or "AB352"` spreadsheet notation or by a (row, col) zero-based integer 2-tuple. So "A4" and (3,0) are ways to access the same cell.

A cell is an object with two components: `value` and `value_type`. Typical code is something like

```
cell = sheet[ (row,col) ]
t,v = cell.value_type, cell.value
if t is None:
    # the cell is empty, convert to empty string
    thing = ''
elif t == "string":
    thing = v
elif t == "float":
    # this is an all-digits product code which got stored as a number
    thing = str( int( v))
```

You do have to be on your guard for user data that's not the type you were expecting: `1O4` is not one hundred and four, it's a three-character string with a letter O in the middle!

There are other `value_type`s than None, "string" and "float". "date" springs to mind. For more details on his and the various other methods of ezodf objects, consult the doc.